# Why can I access all my files without a password when booting with a Chakra Linux live CD?

Tags: security, password, livecd

The other day I burned a Chakra Linux iso on a dvd. When I booted into a live session I was able to access all my regular data. In dolphin when clicking on the icon belonging to my `/home/user` partition a pop-up asked me for my `sudo` password. The password I entered was not my regular `sudo` password, but the password that belongs to the live dvd. By default, this password is always `root`. Using the default password I was granted access to all partitions where I have stored my data, installed Linux Mint and installed Windows 7.

I consider this to be a serious security breach. What is the point of having a password-protected account when all data can be accessed without the password by using a live dvd? Is this behaviour normal, or is something messed up on my system or is there something wrong with the Chakra distro?

Comment: I just want to add to the answers below that this is the same on _any_ OS, it is not a weakness of Linux or *nix, as soon as you have physical access to a machine, that machine is compromised unless it's data are encrypted, period. This is the same for all OSs.

Comment: @terdon It is still compromised, even if the data is encrypted, because anyone can "[evil maid](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html)" the encryption loader.

Comment: @ChrisDown fair enough, even worse then. As soon as you have physical access to a machine, that machine is compromised period. We all know the only secure computer is in a locked room, in an underground facility, is never connected to any networks and is kept permanently turned off.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that even a encrypted drive is compromised! If used correctly it's impervious to attack, even with the "evil maid" vector. Saying it's compromised against "evil maid" is no diff. than if they broke into my house and stuck a gun to my head, and saying the drive is compromised that way too.

Comment: @slm Well, I would certainly consider your hypothetical situation to also be a compromise. I'll forego the xkcd link...

Comment: compromise - an agreement or a settlement of a dispute that is reached by each side making concessions. I think the problem is that word, I know it's what's used to define this, but it's anything but... 8-)

Comment: "an endangering, especially of reputation; exposure to danger, suspicion, etc.: a compromise of one's integrity" -- http://english.stackexchange.com/a/30740

Comment: It gets even worse: with chroot you can install compromised software (rootkits) which will give you complete control of the system without the owner even noticing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an attacker can boot a live CD in your environment, your environment is not secure. This is one of the reasons why physical security is so important.

As a general rule, physical access to the machine is all that's ever needed to compromise it. Unix permissions are enforced by the kernel. If you run a live CD and are root, there's no real difference than being root on your own machine; there's nothing special about your environment.

This is expected, and is normal. This is why data encryption is necessary if you want to hide your data from someone who can physically access your machine -- Unix permissions only protect you against an attacker attacking a running machine with a known permissions model, and known constraints (passwords, keys, etc) to stop an attacker from getting those permissions. If the attacker can manipulate the machine, boot into single user mode, boot a live environment, etc, then there's nothing you can do other than encrypt your data.

Encryption is a good first step, but at every step (when you are entering your authentication to decrypt the volume, etc) you are trusting the computer not to lie to you. You cannot trust the computer if you do not at least have good physical security.

Unix permissions require enforcement, and if your environment changes, that enforcement can become unexpectedly weaker.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a serious security breach, this is how Unix & Unix filesystems work. When you booted this live DVD and provided the password to `sudo` that was the password of the live distro, and not your own.

Unless you're using whole drive encryption like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) or [dm-crypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt), anyone can mount your system's hard drive and see any files they want on it, either through one of  the following methods:

1. Using the native OS, booting it into single user mode
2. Booting it with a Live distro, and mounting the hard drive as a secondary device

Additionally on hard drives that are not encrypted, anyone can take (physically remove), and mount it on another system as root, using this 2nd system to gain access to the 1st system's filesystem.

**NOTE:** The same can be done with a Windows drive as well.

So the primary take away for all should be that physical security is the most important aspect to keeping a computer safe!